# Find a one-form $\alpha_0$ such that $\lim_{t\to 0}\hat\Phi_t^*\beta=d\alpha_0$

Tags: differential-forms

**Given before question**: $\hat{\mathbb{X}}_t\circ\hat\Phi_t=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat\Phi_t$ and $$\beta=\frac{(x^2-y^2)dy\wedge dz+2xydz\wedge dx}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ I have shown that $d\beta=0$

**Question**: Let $\hat\Phi_t:U\rightarrow U$ be given by $\hat\Phi_t(x,y,z)=(tx,y,z)$

(**part 1**)Find $\hat{\mathbb{X}}_t$ as defined above, and (**part 2**)find a one-form $\alpha_0$ such that

$$\lim_{t\to0}\hat\Phi_t^*\beta=d\alpha_0$$

**Answer part $1$**: I have found $\hat{\mathbb{X}}_t$ as follows:$\hat{\mathbb{X}}_t(x,y,z)=((\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat\Phi_t)\circ(\hat\Phi_t^{-1}))(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat\Phi_t(\frac{x}{t},y,z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x,y,z)=(x',y',z')$

**Answer part $2$**: $$\lim_{t\to0}\hat\Phi_t^*\beta=d\alpha_0\Leftrightarrow \lim_{t\to0}\beta\circ\hat\Phi_t=d\alpha_0$$

$$\lim_{t\to0}(\beta\circ\hat\Phi_t)(x,y,z)=\lim_{t\to0}\beta(tx,y,z)$$

Since the $x$ component will always be zero in $\beta$ we get:

$$\lim_{t\to0}\beta(tx,y,z)=\lim_{t\to0}\beta(0,y,z)=\frac{-y^2dy\wedge dz}{y^4}=-\frac{1}{y^2}dy\wedge dz$$

Therefore $d\alpha_0=-\frac{1}{y^2}dy\wedge dz$

**Point of contention**: How do I compute this last result? What is $\alpha_0$ if $d\alpha_0=-\frac{1}{y^2}dy\wedge dz$?

I have never found the integral of a wedge product, how should I do this part? I may be able to work it out through trial and error, but I would prefer a method to use. Are there any standard results to know for computing integrals of this kind (Integral of $2$-forms)?

**Extra**: Just realised that I did not take into account the limit, how does this affect the answer? Would we compute $d\alpha_0=-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{y^2}dy\wedge dz$ or $d\alpha_0=-\frac{1}{y_0^2}dy_0\wedge dz_0$ or what else. I am quite clueless as for this last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $\Bbb X_t$, $\Bbb X_t(\Phi_t(x,y,z)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\Phi_t(x,y,z))$, i.e., $\Bbb X_t(tx,y,z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(tx,y,z)$. Thus $\Bbb X_t(tx,y,z) = (x,0,0)$, and consequently $\Bbb X_t(x,y,z) = (\frac{x}{t},0,0)$. Since $$\Phi_t^*\beta = \frac{t^2x^2 - y^2}{(t^2x^2 + y^2)^2}\, dy\wedge dz - \frac{2txy}{(t^2x^2 + y^2)} t\,dx\wedge dz$$ we have $$\lim_{t \to 0} \Phi_t^*\beta = -\frac{y^2}{y^4}\, dy\wedge dz = -\frac{1}{y^2}\, dy\wedge dz = d\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\wedge dz = d\left(\frac{1}{y}\, dz\right) = d\alpha_0,$$ where $$\alpha_0 = \frac{dz}{y}.$$